# How to prove for any matrix norm, the condition number $\kappa(B)=O(\epsilon^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, condition-number

The inverse of the matrix 
$$
        B=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & -1+\epsilon \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
is 
$$
        B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
        1-\frac{1}{\epsilon} & \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
        -\frac{1}{\epsilon} & \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

how to prove that for any matrix norm, the condition number $\kappa(B)=O(\epsilon^{-1})$ ?

I know that 
\begin{align}
\kappa(B)&=|||B^{-1}|||\cdot|||B|||\\
 & =  \frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot|||\begin{matrix}
        \epsilon-1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}|||\cdot|||\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & -1+\epsilon \\
        \end{matrix}|||\\ 
\end{align}

How to prove that $|||\begin{matrix}
        \epsilon-1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}|||\cdot|||\begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & -1+\epsilon \\
        \end{matrix}||| $ contain some constant term？

Comment: What definition of the condition number are you using? Are there assumptions on $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, so pick any convenient norm.

One simple one is the Frobenius norm which gives
$\kappa (B) = \sqrt{3+(1-\epsilon)^2} \sqrt{{3 \over \epsilon^2} + {(1-\epsilon)^2 \over \epsilon^2}}$.

We can write $\kappa (B) = {1 \over |\epsilon|} (3+ (1-\epsilon)^2)$.